# Webpack devserver proxy, how to avoid 401 error?

Tags: javascript, proxy, react-redux, axios, webpack-dev-server

I am facing a problem that I do not know how to solve.
I have a project, and I am using React and Redux for the frontend, and Springboot for the backend.

Frontend : `http://localhost:8080`
Backend : `http://localhost:8090`

Webpack versions:

```
"webpack": "^4.17.2",
"webpack-cli": "^3.0.7",
"webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.7"
```

Here is my webpack.config.js

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: [
        'react-hot-loader/patch',
        './src/index.js'
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: ['babel-loader']
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx']
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/dist',
        publicPath: '/',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
    ],
    devServer: {
        contentBase: './dist',
        hot: true,
        historyApiFallback: true,
        headers: {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": '*',
            "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": '*'
        },
        proxy: [{
            context: ['/oauth/**', '/flows/**', '/flow/**', '/flowDetail/**', '/flowDetails/**', '/templateDetail/**', '/templateDetails/**', '/usersUnix/**', '/userUnix/**'],
            target: 'http://localhost:8090',
            changeOrigin: true
        }],
    }
};
```

I call the url via axios (v0.18.0) like this :

```
axios.get('/flows/search/findByUserId?userId=2&page=0&size=5', {headers: {Authorization: Bearer}})
axios.get('/flows/' + id, {headers: {Authorization: Bearer}})
```

The code works fine, but when I try to reload the page with the following url :

```
axios.get('/flows/' + id, {headers: {Authorization: Bearer}})
```

I can open the open this page by a link from the main page. But the server won't reload the page, I have a 401 error. I can not reload the page. Don't know why ...
This error happened since I have implemented the proxy configuration. Before, with not proxy, I was able to load/reload every single page.

I do not understand why I can not reload this specific page/url.

Here is the exact error message I have when I try to reload the second URL :
[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: You are receiving 401 right then your proxy is working fine. The Authorization is not passing. Can you share the headers for the route you are getting 401?

Comment: Sure, the headers looks like this, I store a token into the getState().auth :
var sessionState = getState().auth
const Bearer = 'Bearer ' + sessionState.session.access_token

Comment: Can you post the screenshot of that HTTP request in networks tab?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the **axios {Authorization: Bearer }** headers. You are not passing the headers when you reload the page. Try checking the Authorization headers are being passed in the header under network tab of the browser